# Change in the rootnode

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

> Old Input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SalesOrder>
    <SalesOrderHeader>
        <OrderNumber>
            <BuyerOrderNumber>3016</BuyerOrderNumber>
        </OrderNumber>
    </SalesOrderHeader>
    <SalesOrderDetail>
        <ListOfItemDetail>
            <ItemDetail>
                <BaseItemDetail>
                    <LineItemNum>
                        <BuyerLineItemNum>00001</BuyerLineItemNum>
                    </LineItemNum>
                </BaseItemDetail>
            </ItemDetail>
            <ItemDetail>
                <BaseItemDetail>
                    <LineItemNum>
                        <BuyerLineItemNum>00002</BuyerLineItemNum>
                    </LineItemNum>
                </BaseItemDetail>
            </ItemDetail>
        </ListOfItemDetail>
    </SalesOrderDetail>
</SalesOrder>
```

> Old Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/SalesOrder">
        <ns0:Z_SALES_ORDER xmlns:ns0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" >
            <SHEADER>
                <xsl:call-template name="sHeader"/>
            </SHEADER>
            <SITEM>
                <xsl:call-template name="sItem"/>
            </SITEM>
    </ns0:Z_SALES_ORDER>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="sHeader">
        <SNUMBER>
            <xsl:value-of select="SalesOrderHeader/OrderNumber/BuyerOrderNumber "/>
        </SNUMBER>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="sItem">
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::ItemDetail">
            <item>
                <B_ITEM>
                    <xsl:value-of select="BaseItemDetail/LineItemNum/BuyerLineItemNum"/>
                </B_ITEM>
                </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> Required Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Z_SALES_ORDER xmlns:ns0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
    <SHEADER>
        <SNUMBER>3016</SNUMBER>
    </SHEADER>
    <SITEM>
        <item>
            <B_ITEM>00001</B_ITEM>
        </item>
        <item>
            <B_ITEM>00002</B_ITEM>
        </item>
    </SITEM>
</ns0:Z_SALES_ORDER>
```

> Query: Now there is some change in the source xml. In the SalesOrder
>   rootnode they pass other info as well. The input file is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SalesOrder xmlns="abc:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v4/xcbl4.xsd" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
    <SalesOrderHeader>
        <OrderNumber>
            <BuyerOrderNumber>3016</BuyerOrderNumber>
        </OrderNumber>
    </SalesOrderHeader>
    <SalesOrderDetail>
        <ListOfItemDetail>
            <ItemDetail>
                <BaseItemDetail>
                    <LineItemNum>
                        <BuyerLineItemNum>00001</BuyerLineItemNum>
                    </LineItemNum>
                </BaseItemDetail>
            </ItemDetail>
            <ItemDetail>
                <BaseItemDetail>
                    <LineItemNum>
                        <BuyerLineItemNum>00002</BuyerLineItemNum>
                    </LineItemNum>
                </BaseItemDetail>
            </ItemDetail>
        </ListOfItemDetail>
    </SalesOrderDetail>
</SalesOrder>
```

Could you please tell me,how to get the same output which I was getting using the old input xml file.

**EDIT**
Query: In the SalesOrder rootnode they pass other info as well. The input file is below. How to get the rootnode info using XSLT?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SalesOrder xmlns="abc:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v4/xcbl4.xsd" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
    <SalesOrderHeader>
        <OrderNumber>
            <BuyerOrderNumber>3016</BuyerOrderNumber>
        </OrderNumber>
    </SalesOrderHeader>
</SalesOrder>
```

Comment: Hi - I've taken the liberty of restoring our original Q and A and appending your amendments as Edits at the end of each - this way others in the community can view the full thread. With your new Q, do you mean that you want to copy (verbatim) the entire SalesOrderHeader element into your output 'as-is'? Or perhaps do you mean you want to keep all the new namespaces (SOAP-ENV, SOAP-ENC) in the ns0:Z_SALES_ORDER root element output as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that the new XML has a namespace you need to qualify your xpath with this namespace. Easiest is to use an alias:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:abc="abc:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v4/xcbl4.xsd"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                exclude-result-prefixes="abc xsl"
                >
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/abc:SalesOrder">
        <ns0:Z_SALES_ORDER xmlns:ns0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" >
            <SHEADER>
                <xsl:call-template name="sHeader"/>
            </SHEADER>
            <SITEM>
                <xsl:call-template name="sItem"/>
            </SITEM>
        </ns0:Z_SALES_ORDER>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="sHeader">
        <SNUMBER>
            <xsl:value-of select="abc:SalesOrderHeader/abc:OrderNumber/abc:BuyerOrderNumber "/>
        </SNUMBER>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="sItem">
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::abc:ItemDetail">
            <item>
                <B_ITEM>
                    <xsl:value-of select="abc:BaseItemDetail/abc:LineItemNum/abc:BuyerLineItemNum"/>
                </B_ITEM>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit (Sara)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:abc="abc:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v4/xcbl4.xsd" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="abc xsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/abc:SalesOrder">
    <ns0:Z_SALES_ORDER xmlns:ns0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
     <SNUMBER>
      <xsl:value-of select="abc:SalesOrderHeader/abc:OrderNumber/abc:BuyerOrderNumber "/>
     </SNUMBER>
    </ns0:Z_SALES_ORDER>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable solution.